# Ionic for mobile web development

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to develop a mobile website( not App), but I need to have similar UI of the Ionic Angular mobile App.

Can I use ionic framework for the mobile web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, and even with Ionic 1 (even though they don't officially support it). However, with Ionic 2 they officially said that they support the web apps as well.

I personally used Ionic 1 for this scenario as well and made the app to load in a simple iframe. You basically take the contents of your Ionic `www` folder and place it on the web server and you have a web app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I made a rather quite long tutorial about all this, so you're free to take a look: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/front-end-javascript/ionic-framework-a-definitive-10-000-word-guide

Comment: Hi, is there any tool where I can prototype bootstrap UI for mobile website? I am specifically looking for the side menu

Comment: Check out the ionic creator: https://creator.ionic.io. And also, may not be what you're looking for but have you checked out https://www.invisionapp.com/?